# How to send datagridview1 row to datagridview2

Tags: c#

I have two datagridview `datagridview1` and `datagridview2`.`datagridview1`get all of the values from db and it's work fine. What I want is; in some situation I need to send `datagridview1` row to `datagridview2`

My code like this;

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
baglantı = new SqlConnection();
baglantı.ConnectionString = 

"Server=asdsa;Database=asdsasd;User Id=asdsa;password=adsadsas";
baglantı.Open();

komut = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table" , baglantı);
ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
komut.Fill(ds, "table");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "SATICI ADI";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "ALICI ADI";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "URUN";
dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "ADET";
dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "SATICI PUANI";
dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "ALICI PUANI";
dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "TARIH";

dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "SATICI ADI");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "ALICI ADI");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "URUN");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "ADET");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "SATICI PUANI");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "ALICI PUANI");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "TARIH");

int i = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (i != 20496)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString() && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[1].Value.ToString() && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[2].Value.ToString() && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Value.ToString() && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[4].Value.ToString() && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[5].Value.ToString() && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[6].Value.ToString())
        {
            CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
            currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
            currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();

            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This situation is;

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

In this situation I need to send dataGridView1.Rows[i] to dataGridView2.Rows

Comment: `dataGridView2.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);`?

Comment: it says "Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control."

Comment: Define 'Send'! Is it copy or move?

Comment: Add `table2` to your `dataset` with no row, bind it to `dataGridView2`, and add appropriate rows to `table2` and remove them from `table` (the old one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `datagridView2.Rows.Add(dataGridview1.Rows[i].Cell[0].value,dataGridview1.Rows[i].Cell[1].value, ...)`
İt will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'send', do you mean superficially append a row from `dataGridView1` to `dataGridView2`?
Have you considered binding `dataGridView2` to a `BindingList<T>` you can `Add()` to?

Comment: When you say 'send', do you mean superficially append a row from dataGridView1 to dataGridView2? YES that I want

Comment: Looking at your other comment, and if it's only superficial, I think you will have to create a *new* `DataGridViewRow` from the old one, and `Add()` that instead.

Comment: In my code I try to find duplicate value and when I find it I use this code dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false; so When I find this duplicate value I need to view on datagridview2 because datagridview1 is distinct values and datagridview2 is duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

From you previous comment, you can easily get distinct or duplicate values from database directly, which will be faster.

Moreover your logic is incorrect to find the duplicate values, you are comparing values each consecutive rows, but you need two for loop